# How do you upload .zip to .mcpack?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ios

So while I was trying to import a .zip file from planet Minecraft, I followed all the instructions to turn it into .mcpack. While I did that, I imported it to Minecraft and an error with no log comes up. .mcworld works but not .mcpack.
Note: I use iPadOS v.13.6 using a iPad Pro (9.6 inch) model. I don’t know if that will help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This likely has to do with the manifest.json file. could you please turn it into a .txt file and add a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would just rename the `bar.zip` to `bar.mcworld`, however it wouldn't matter anyway because imports are currently broken on iOS and must be done via direct sharing with another app (not Safari or Files).